# Как динамически брать значения из нескольких инпутов и подставлять их в див?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть див в текстом и есть 4 пустых инпута. Нужно, если все 4 инпута заполнены, то динамически подставлять все их значения в этот див, а если хотя бы один не заполнен, то оставлять див без изменений. Как это реализовать?

Comment: Проверяете на заполненность высе инпуты и если заполнены, то копируете `value` каждого инпута в `div` :)

Answer (score 2):

нечто подобное?

```js
$("input").keyup(function(){
   var values = $("input").map(function(){ return $(this).val(); })
                   .get()
                   .filter(v => v.trim() != "");
   
   
   if(values.length == 4){ 
      $("div").text( values.join(',') );
   }
  
});
```

```css
div {
   min-height: 50px;
   border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>text</div>

<input type="text"/>
<input type="text"/>
<input type="text"/>
<input type="text"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно как-то так

```js
const values = {
inp1:null,
inp2:null,
inp3:null,
inp4:null
}

function setContent(event){
const inputId = event.target.id
const value = event.target.value
values[inputId] = value

if(Object.keys(values).every(key=>!!values[key] && values[key]!=='')){
 const text = Object.keys(values).map(key=>values[key])
  $('#content').text(text.map(value=>value))
}

}

$('#inp1').on('input', setContent)
$('#inp2').on('input', setContent)
$('#inp3').on('input', setContent)
$('#inp4').on('input', setContent)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id='inp1' />
<input id='inp2' />
<input id='inp3' />
<input id='inp4' />

<div id='content'></div>
```

Comment: Тяжелое решение, но имеет право на существование.